# How to Adjust Spacing in Xcode Auto-completed Text? (Text Injection Formatting)?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

Is there any way to adjust spacing constraints in Xcode when Xcode is performing autocomplete?  I'm looking for a way to have spaces inside of <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>, and always have a space after <kbd>:</kbd> but not before.

For example I type this:

```
if (
```

it auto-creates this:

```
  if (condition) {
      code
  }
```

but I want spaces inside the parans like this:

```
  if ( condition ) {
      code
  }
```

and before we go down the road of custom code snippets (of which I have a bucket full), I'm also talking about when you select something and type a <kbd>(</kbd> which then puts that selected-something in between parantheses.

Or in objective C and you type a <kbd>[</kbd> while something is selected and the selection gets surrounded nicely with <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> but is smashed against the selection like:

```
theError postAlertNotification
```

select `theError postAlertNotification` and type <kbd>[</kbd> and get this:

```
[theError postAlertNotification]
```

but want this:

```
[ theError postAlertNotification ]
```

The list goes on and these are only a couple of examples.  I have been digging into the com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist file but nothing looks obvious.